# TYPO3 frontend login always returns wrong user / password

Tags: authentication, typo3, frontend, typo3-8.x

I am struggling to create a frontend login in TYPO3. I followed instructions on https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/EditorsTutorial/AccessControl/Login/Index.html but it is impossible to log in with the given user. It always says wrong user / password.

- generated a folder for fe-users
- activated module felogin
- generated a fe-user in the folder for fe-users
- RSA disabled and deleted
- no redirect after login

TYPO3 8.7.4

Does anyone have an idea of what else could go wrong? Thank you

Comment: Have you selected the storage page id in the plugin settings?

Comment: yes, I selected a the storage folder in the plugin settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have not used `rsaauth` then changed loginSecurityLevel `rsa` to `normal` in `LocalConfiguration.php` file. Like below.

```
'FE' => [
    'debug' => true,
    'loginSecurityLevel' => 'normal',
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like no cookies are allowed. For a login you need cookies being enabled.
And the cookies need to match the domain and protocol, (https != http)

Answer (score 0):

If cookies are okay, then perhaps your TypoScript doesn't load the JavaScript file (should default to load, but you can prevent this) which is necessary for salting and/or RSA encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the storage pid for your users in the constant `styles.content.loginform.pid`?